# Making common units within a column of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has measurements with different units in the same column.  A separate column exists for the unit names.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['red','green','blue','blue','green'],
                   'length': [3,6,9,120,15],
                   'length_units': ['ft','m','ft','cm','ft'],
                   'width': [48,700,120,130,188],
                   'width_units': ['in','cm','in','cm','in'],
                  })
print(df)
```

```
   color  length length_units  width width_units
0    red       3           ft     48          in
1  green       6            m    700          cm
2   blue       9           ft    120          in
3   blue     120           cm    130          cm
4  green      15           ft    188          in
```

So my goal would be to convert each column to a particular common unit.  For instance, in this example, I'd like to convert all lengths to feet and all widths to inches, so that it looked like:

```
   color     length length_units      width width_units
0    red   3.000000           ft   48.00000          in
1  green  19.685040           ft  275.59070          in
2   blue   9.000000           ft  120.00000          in
3   blue   3.937008           ft   51.18113          in
4  green  15.000000           ft  188.00000          in
```

I'm very new to pandas, and I've come up with an ugly and inefficient solution with lots of filtering, slicing, and apply().  I'd love to see how it should really be done!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a `dict` of `dicts` where the keys are your desired units and the value is a dict with all conversions to that unit (that are required in your data). Then given your consistent naming conventions of the columns, use a simple loop to map the unit to its conversion and multiply by the value, and set the _units column.

```
d = {'ft': {'ft': 1, 'm': 3.2808, 'cm': .032808},
     'in': {'in': 1, 'cm': 0.3937}}

for col, unit in [('length', 'ft'), ('width', 'in')]:
    df[col] = df[col] * df[f'{col}_units'].map(d[unit])
    df[f'{col}_units'] = unit
```

---

```
   color    length length_units    width width_units
0    red   3.00000           ft   48.000          in
1  green  19.68480           ft  275.590          in
2   blue   9.00000           ft  120.000          in
3   blue   3.93696           ft   51.181          in
4  green  15.00000           ft  188.000          in
```

---

For a lot more flexibility, instead of the `dict` of `dicts` you could create the NxN matrix of conversions, let's call it `df_conv`:

```
            mm         cm          m        km            in           ft           yd            mi           nmi
mm         1.0       0.10     0.0010  0.000001      0.039370     0.003281     0.001094  6.213712e-07  5.399568e-07
cm        10.0       1.00     0.0100  0.000010      0.393701     0.032808     0.010936  6.213712e-06  5.399568e-06
m       1000.0     100.00     1.0000  0.001000     39.370079     3.280840     1.093613  6.213712e-04  5.399568e-04
km   1000000.0  100000.00  1000.0000  1.000000  39370.078740  3280.839895  1093.613298  6.213712e-01  5.399568e-01
in        25.4       2.54     0.0254  0.000025      1.000000     0.083333     0.027778  1.578283e-05  1.371490e-05
ft       304.8      30.48     0.3048  0.000305     12.000000     1.000000     0.333333  1.893939e-04  1.645788e-04
yd       914.4      91.44     0.9144  0.000914     36.000000     3.000000     1.000000  5.681818e-04  4.937365e-04
mi   1609344.0  160934.40  1609.3440  1.609344  63360.000000  5280.000000  1760.000000  1.000000e+00  8.689762e-01
nmi  1852000.0  185200.00  1852.0000  1.852000  72913.385827  6076.115486  2025.371829  1.150779e+00  1.000000e+00
```

And now you can use those Series to map to any unit you've included in that matrix

```
for col, unit in [('length', 'ft'), ('width', 'in')]:
    df[col] = df[col]*df[f'{col}_units'].map(df_conv[unit])
    df[f'{col}_units'] = unit
```

Comment: Nice `df_conv` idea. Feels much cleaner than `dict`.

Comment: @tdy yup, I couldn't find a handy dataset that was more exhaustive than that on a quick search, but surely one exists with all of the possible conversions.